# Assign props.data to state

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I'm trying to assign a prop.data from graphql to a state.  The props.data is an array. I keep getting IMEIs as an empty array.  Any ideas?

```
this.state = {
    IMEIs: []
}


this.setState({IMEIs: this.props.data.checkIMEI})
```

Comment: What do you get from console.log of this.props.data.checkIMEI, before setting the stare?

Comment: Well you said it yourself, "props.data is an array". You are trying to read `IMEIs` property of an array, which won't work.

Comment: One thing I don't understand: if you get it from props, why don't you keep using the props values, and set local state from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out.  Graphql was not refreshed with the props need I had to delay it for one more cycle